# How do I split a cell and create new concatenated field?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

So I have fields like `Fruit-Apple-25` , `Vegetable-Tomato-22` in a row. Can I create a new field where I can name it as `Fr_Grp_App` , `Vg_Grp_Tm`. What I am using now is to just select if its apple or tomato but not add the other prefixes. How can I do that.

`if(not(iserror(find("Apple",D3))),"Apple",if(not(iserror(find("Tomato",D3))),"Tomato")`

So if its Fruit then it should be Fr in the prefix and if its Vegetable it should be Vg as prefix

Comment: @BigBen  just added more details

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have a lookup table, it has to be an abbr for fruit or vegetable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't ask for it, but I think doing this in a UDF will give you a lot more control over how you define these groups and allow you to scale up without getting bogged down in a really horrible string manipulating formula.

To do this, create a new Module in VBE and paste this in:

```
Public Function FoodGroup(foodString As String) As String
    'Variables
    Dim Group As String
    Dim Food As String

    'Get the incoming group and food name from the string
    Group = Split(foodString, "-")(0)
    Food = Split(foodString, "-")(1)

    'Handle group names
    Select Case Group
        Case "Fruit"
            Group = "Frt"
        Case "Vegetable"
            Group = "Veg"
    End Select

    'Handle Fruit Names
    Select Case Food
        Case "Tomato"
            Food = "Tm"
        Case "Apple"
            Food = "App"
    End Select

    'Return
    FoodGroup = Group & "-Grp-" & Food

End Function
```

Save your workbook and you can then use this new UDF in your workbook:

[image]